# SQL: Add a new column based on CASE expression and looking up values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, alter-table

I am trying to add a new column called Multiplier to an existing table called Trades. The row values of this column will depend on another column on the Trades table called Type. If the Type is anything other than "Equity", "Corp" or "Option, then the value needs to be looked up from another table called ContractSize. Lastly, I want the data type of the Multiplier column to be decimal (7,3). The code I had was:

```
ALTER TABLE Portfolio.Trades
ADD Multiplier decimal(7,3) AS
(
CASE 
 WHEN Type = 'Equity' Then 1
 WHEN Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
 WHEN Type = 'Option' Then 100
ELSE
 (SELECT ContractSize FROM Portfolio.ContractSize CS
 JOIN Portfolio.Trades T
 ON T.Identifier = CS.ContractSize)
)
```

I am getting two errors on this code:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Some guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create this as a 'calculated' column in the table?  Or just trying to set the initial values for existing data after creating the column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in two steps:

```
ALTER TABLE Portfolio.Trades ADD Multiplier decimal(7,3);

UPDATE T
    SET Multiplier = (CASE WHEN T.Type = 'Equity' Then 1
                           WHEN T.Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
                           WHEN T.Type = 'Option' Then 100
                           ELSE (SELECT CS.ContractSize
                                 FROM Portfolio.ContractSize CS
                                 WHERE T.Identifier = CS.ContractSize)
                       END)
    FROM Portfolio.Trades T;
```

I am guessing that the `ON`/correlation condition is incorrect.  If it is correct, you can just do:

```
UPDATE T
    SET Multiplier = (CASE WHEN T.Type = 'Equity' Then 1
                           WHEN T.Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
                           WHEN T.Type = 'Option' Then 100
                           ELSE T.Identifier)
                       END)
    FROM Portfolio.Trades T;
```

Or even just add this as a computed column.

Comment: Yes that ON correlation should be. T.Identifier = CS.Identifier.

Comment: Thanks, this works but strangely, only after I take out the alias T and do this instead:     UPDATE Portfolio.Trades 
SET Multiplier =
(
 CASE 
  WHEN Type = 'Equity' Then 1
  WHEN Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
  WHEN Type = 'Option' Then 100
 ELSE
  (SELECT ContractSize FROM Portfolio.ContractSize CS
   WHERE Portfolio.Trades.Identifier = CS.Identifier)
 END
)

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep because sql-server syntax for UPDATE with an alias  is `UPDATE Portfolio.Trades FROM Portfolio.Trades T` ...

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep . . . The original syntax works in most databases.  SQL Server has a slightly different syntax.  Because there was no database tag, I just used the more general syntax.

Comment: The old records now show the Multiplier values I want but how do I update for new records? The Multiplier shows a NULL value for new records. If I re-run the above code, it will work but it will go through all 60,000 rows again instead of the 10 new rows that were added.

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep . . . You might be able to do all this with a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Every CASE statement must have a END keyword at the end of the condition. In this case it should be like this.

```
ALTER TABLE Portfolio.Trades
ADD Multiplier decimal(7,3) AS
(
CASE 
 WHEN Type = 'Equity' Then 1
 WHEN Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
 WHEN Type = 'Option' Then 100
ELSE
 (SELECT ContractSize FROM Portfolio.ContractSize CS
 JOIN Portfolio.Trades T
 ON T.Identifier = CS.ContractSize)END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why add column to the table? You can create a view alternatively.

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
    SELECT *, -- your real column list here
        CAST(CASE
         WHEN Type = 'Equity' Then 1
         WHEN Type = 'Corp' Then 0.1
         WHEN Type = 'Option' Then 100
         ELSE
           (SELECT ContractSize 
            FROM Portfolio.ContractSize CS
            WHERE T.Identifier = CS.ContractSize)
         END AS decimal(7,3)) AS  Multiplier
    FROM
    Portfolio.Trades T;
```