# Creating a new column in Teradata using CASE statement

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to create a new column in a table in Teradata using a CASE Statement

I am trying a create a new column called ID_Number_Mod from a CASE Statement based off an original column  called ID_Number from the table. Below is my code

```
alter table Table_A
add  (case
when char_length(cast(cast(ID_Number as bigint) as varchar(50)))=12 then cast('999000' as char(6)) || cast(cast( substr(cast(cast(ID_Number as bigint) as char(12)), 4, 12) as bigint) as char(15))
else ID_Number end) as ID_Number_Mod float;
```

I am getting the below syntax error

> "expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier
>   between '(' and the 'case' keyword

Comment: Do `teradata` support this query? IMO you should add column `ID_Number_Mod` first, then use an update query to update that columns values

Comment: Teradata doesn't support calculated columns, put it in a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your query to

```
alter table Table_A
    add ID_Number_Mod as (
        case
            when char_length(cast(cast(ID_Number as bigint) as varchar(50)))=12 then cast('999000' as char(6)) || cast(cast( substr(cast(cast(ID_Number as bigint) as char(12)), 4, 12) as bigint) as char(15))
            else ID_Number end);
```

Comment: I changed the query and I am getting expected something like a TRANSCATIONTIME keyword between AS keyword and '(' error

Comment: Try doing it in two steps: First update your table with your column and then modify the column to set the value using case statement.Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976581/sql-add-a-new-column-based-on-case-expression-and-looking-up-values-from-anothe